# Hacer sumatoria de valor menor a un año y a un mes en especifico

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un inconveniente con una consulta en MySQL y no logro comprender qué tengo mal, les explico para ver si no veo algo o me hace falta algo.
Tengo una tabla MySQL con unos campos de valores mes a mes, año a año por cada cliente. Deseo tener la sumatoria de cada cliente de la columna valor a un corte
de año y mes X, es decir, requiero el acumulado hasta esa fecha, tengo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT dlin_codcli, dlin_anoliq, dlin_mesliq, SUM(IFNULL(dlin_valint, 0)) AS dlin_valint
    FROM coo_detintaportes
    WHERE dlin_codcli = '32861467'
    AND dlin_anoliq <= 2019
    AND dlin_mesliq <= 1
```

En teroria debería salir la sumatoria de dlin_valint desde enero de 2019 hacia atras, pues solo me muestra el valor del mes de enero y no se por qué sucede.
Si quito el filtro del mes de la consulta sí me da bien, pero me da el valor hasta el día de hoy, osea, el mes de marzo, ¿qué será?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que estás condicionando mal el mes. Pese a que pones <= 2019, el "and" indica que solo sean los menores del mes de enero, por ende solo va a conciderar los años anteriores al 2019 pero solo su mes de enero. Cambia tu condición de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT dlin_codcli, dlin_anoliq, dlin_mesliq, SUM(IFNULL(dlin_valint, 0)) AS dlin_valint
FROM coo_detintaportes
WHERE dlin_codcli = '32861467'
  AND (dlin_anoliq < 2019 -- menores al año 2019.
    or dlin_mesliq = 1)  -- si es el 2019, sólo concidere el mes de enero.
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ya la he probado y hasta donde hice las pruebas me trabaja bien.

Voy a jugar con las fechas un poco mas pero creo que me sirve, voy a ahora a entender la consulta, no habia caído en cuenta de eso.

Comment: Dale no te preocupes, en todo caso si te sirvió al 100%, no olvides marcar la respuesta como válida.

Comment: Rostan, mil gracias por la colaboración. Efectivament como tu me comentas, con el código que me pasas me da la sumatoria que requiero, solo me toco hacer un pequeño cambio, pues no solo necesito el acumulado de años anteriores sino de los meses transcurridos en el año actual. Modifique tu código y le he puesto **dlin_mesliq <= <<mes de corte>>**, con esto me toma todos los meses hasta el que yo necesito.

SELECT dlin_codcli, SUM(IFNULL(dlin_valint, 0)) AS dlin_valint
FROM coo_detintaportes
WHERE dlin_codcli = '32861467'
  AND (dlin_anoliq < 2019
    or dlin_mesliq <= 1)

Comment: Dale! es un guto haberte ayudado! suerte y exitos!

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es la suma de todos los años anteriores a 2019 (sin importar el mes), y si el año es 2019 entonces solo considerar enero. Por lo tanto la consulta tiene que reflejar esto...

La solución podría ser así:

```
SELECT dlin_codcli, dlin_anoliq, dlin_mesliq, SUM(IFNULL(dlin_valint, 0)) AS dlin_valint
FROM coo_detintaportes
WHERE dlin_codcli = '32861467'
AND (dlin_anoliq < 2019 OR (dlin_anoliq = 2019 AND dlin_mesliq <= 1))
```